# Enable VT-X and VT-D in the bios for a PowerEdge r910. Ubuntu Server Bionic

Tags: virtualization, dell-poweredge, bios, passthrough, intel-vt-x

I am trying to enable VT-X and VT-D on a PowerEdge r910. I have set "Virtualization Enabled"in the bios settings and also "SR_IOV Global Enable".

I still get the following on the Ubuntu Server deployment (18.04 Bionic):

```
ubuntu@moral-sponge:~$ sudo dmesg | grep DMAR
[    0.000000] ACPI: DMAR 0x000000007F38E7F4 000248 (v01 DELL   PE_SC3   00000001 DELL 00000001)
[    0.000000] DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: Your BIOS is broken; DMAR reported at address 0!
[    0.000000] DMAR: Host address width 44
[    0.000000] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x00000000000000 flags: 0x0
[    0.000000] DMAR: Parse DMAR table failure.
```

The bios version is 2.12.0. As far as I can see so far that is the latest version.

Comment: Only Dell can fix the BIOS.

Comment: So hoping something like coreboot really takes hold for enterprise server hardware to make this situation better.